# selecting elements using variables in ruby /watir

Tags: ruby, watir

The real issue I am encountering is the delay on population of drop down lists in a web page.

The call i am using in the script is :-

```
   clickOndropDown(":id","dropDownAutocomplete","ABC",@b)
```

where 
1. clickOndropDown is the method invoked
2. id is the element selector (which can  be :id,xpath, or :css [which are different selectors in my html code for different dropdown boxes]  to handle all cases within the code)
3. ABC is the element to be selected from the drop down list
4. @b is the browser object

the function definition is as :

```
    def clickOndropDown(identifier,selector,targetVal,br)

            begin
                puts "starting off"     # gets printed
                br.element("#{identifier}" => "#{selector}").fire_event :click #--- does not work--- 
                # br.element(:id => "#{selector}").fire_event :click           #--- works 
                puts "inside selector pass 1"

                br.element(:link, targetVal).fire_event :click  
               ...
               ...
               # rest of the code
```

It does not throw any exception..just does  the push statement before the selection statement.

is there any wild card handler for # (--"#{identifier}" ) so that I can write a single code for handling id,xpath,or css

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised that there is no exception. I would expect a `MissingWayOfFindingObjectException`.

The problem is that the identifier is a `String` instead of a `Symbol`. The line that is not working is equivalent to:

```
br.element(":id" => "dropDownAutocomplete")
```

Which is not the same as:

```
br.element(:id => "dropDownAutocomplete")
```

Notice the difference between the `String`, `":id"`, and the `Symbol`, `:id`.

You should change the method call to send a `Symbol` and change the method to no longer change it to a `String`:

```
def clickOndropDown(identifier,selector,targetVal,br)
  br.element(identifier => selector).fire_event :click
end

clickOndropDown(:id,"dropDownAutocomplete","ABC",@b)
```

If you want to have a more versatile method, you would be better off to have the `clickOndropDown` accept a `Hash` for the locator. This would allow you to accept multiple locator criteria.

```
def click_on_dropdown(br, target_val, locator)
  br.element(locator).fire_event :click
end

# Call for the original example
click_on_dropdown(@b, "ABC", id: "dropDownAutocomplete")

# Call with multiple selectors
click_on_dropdown(@b, "ABC", id: "dropDownAutocomplete", name: "name_value")
```

Comment: Thank you very much...Will try the multiple locator criteria to see it it resolves the issue

Comment: @ShinuJohn, did you get this working?  I'm running into a similar issue and could use the assistance.  Thank you.

Comment: Nate 
I created an oveloaded method with the 3 different parameters being passed to the method as applicable.. Xpath css or id...
Xpath is most unreliable
..css and the id...i added a sleep to make sure the dropdown elements are able to populate after a callback to generate the contents of the drop down list... Will post the snippet once i access the dev machine

Comment: Call : clickOndropDown("id","dropDownAutocomplete","1",@b)

Comment: def clickOndropDown(identifier,selector,targetVal,br)
  maxattempts = 3
  attempt=1
   begin
     ClickBasedonID(identifier,selector,br)
           sleep 1
           br.element(:link, targetVal).fire_event :click
      rescue 
       attempt += 1
       sleep 1
        ClickBasedonID(identifier,selector,br)
       if(attempt > maxattempts)
        puts "element " + selector.to_s + " cannot be clicked"           
    else 
      sleep 1
      retry
    end   
    
      end 
end